# Visio doesn't show shape's icons on Shapes pane

Tags: microsoft-visio

How can I see icons for shapes on the left (Shapes) pane?
When collapsed, I'm able to see icons but, when collapsed, I don't see proper icons.

p.s. I'm in Developer mode.

Collapsed:
[image: Collapsed]

Expanded:
[image: Expanded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click where it says **Shapes** and select **Icons and Names**. Other display options are also available there but that will get you started.

Comment: **Thanks** Paul, it's working